# Angular component with dynamic template created using ɵcompileComponent (Angular 9) is not working in production mode

Tags: angular9, angular-ivy, angular-aot, angular-dynamic-components

I am creating a dynamic component in Angular 9. I have a `<ul>` tag in the html template, the sub-elements of which are dynamically loaded from the server (The server will return values like `<li>One</li><li>Two</li><li (click)="onLinkClicked(3)">Three</li>` using handlebar templates).

```
    private createComponentFromRaw(template: string, containerRef: ElementRef) {
        class DynamicComponent {
            onLinkClicked(resource: any) {
                console.log(resource);
            }
        }

        ɵcompileComponent(DynamicComponent, { template, changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush });
        ɵrenderComponent(DynamicComponent, {
            host: containerRef.nativeElement,
            injector: this.injector,
            hostFeatures: [ɵLifecycleHooksFeature],
        });
    }
```

On calling `this.createComponentFromRaw('<li>One</li>', this.ref.element);` the component is rendered as expected when run as `ng serve` but throws the following error at runtime in production mode (`ng build --prod`):

```
ERROR Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!
  - JIT compilation is discouraged for production use-cases! Consider AOT mode instead.
  - Did you bootstrap using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server'?
  - Alternatively provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only option currently available is to set `buildOptimizer: false` in the `angular.json`

This happens because the buildOptimizer incorrectly considers @angular/compiler as having no side-effects and removes it as part of the tree shaking